# dropdown menu on last table cell gets cut off - React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a react bootstrap table, the last cell on each row has a dropdown menu.  It's fine until the last row, the dropdown menu gets cut off due to `overflow:hidden` in the table element.  I would like to keep this, if I disable it then there will be a long highlight passing the table body height whenever I hover on a column header.  The `overflow hidden` keeps the highlight column relative to the table body.

How can I overcome this issue?  I tried to build my own custom dropdown menu, something like this:

table component:

```
<tbody>
 {this.state.apps.map((app)=>{
                      return <AppRow />;  
                    })}
</tbody>
```

Approw component:

```
<tr>
 <td>cell1</td>
 <td>cell2</td>
 <td>last cell</td>
 <div>dropdown menu</div>
</tr>
```

this setup is fine, it doesn't get cut off but the dropdown menu is alway at the top to the first row, it's supposed to be at top to the corresponding table row.  So if i click on the last row, the dropdown menu doesn't appear in the appropriate table row but to the top of the first table row.

Has any one run into this issue? Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css it should fix the issue.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .table-responsive .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .table-responsive {
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```